# Sympy Binomial plotting

Tags: plot, sympy, distribution

I have the following code sample.  The Normal distribution plots perfectly; whereas the Binomial does not.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import *

X = Binomial('X', 100 ,  S.Half, 1, 0) # AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'evalf'
X =  Normal('n1', 50, 5)               # plots nicely

x = symbols("x")
d = density(X)(x)

plot(d, (x, 0, 100))
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong in trying to plot the Binomial.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from sympy.stats import *
from matplotlib import pyplot
%matplotlib inline

X = Binomial('X', 100 ,  S.Half, 1, 0)
d = density(X)

u = np.arange(0,100)
v1 = [d(i) for i in u]

pyplot.plot(u,v1)
```